# How to check rabbit connection in node js for unit test using mocha and chi

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, mocha.js, chai

I'm using `amqplib`-package for connecting to RabbitMQ in nodeJS and want to know 
how I can check/verify my RabbitMQ-connection using Mocha and Chai in nodeJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try one of the following:

- you can create a valid rabbit-mq connection using a docker iamage [docker-rabbitmq](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) and make real requests to your application but this is not unit testing, but more like integration testing.
- You can mock it using [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) a very good article I can suggest on this topic is [Best practices for spies, stubs, and mocks in sinonjs](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/best-practices-for-spies-stubs-and-mocks-in-sinon-js)
- You can follow this topic on google groups [NodeJS + RabbitMQ (amqplib): How to write good Unit Test against them.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/Eegzba39PD4)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ampqlib package and you want to test whether the connection is established or not then it is not considered as a unit test, we can call it an integration test.

Other answers have good content about integration testing, but for unit testing you can use `amqplib-mocks` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib-mocks) which is a simple mocking framework for amqplib.

For a basic unit test you can check if `amqp.connect(url)` is called and expect the URL you want.

I can also show a basic example how you can get a stubbed connection object:
(ps: This is not a running code, this is just for reference)

subscriber.js

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');
class Subscriber {
   async getConnection(url) {
        const connection = await amqp.connect(url);
        return connection;
   }
}
```

Subscriber class has a method `getConnection` which establishes and return a connection object with rabbitmq.

subscriber.test.js

```
const amqpMock = require('amqplib-mocks');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const mockConnection = await amqpMock.connect('mockurl.com');
const getConnectionStub = sinon.stub(Subscriber.prototype, 'getConnection').returns(mockConnection);
```

In above code you can either stub `ampq.connect` directly or stub `getConnection` method and return a connection object as  returned by amqp-mock's connect method.

To know more about sinon used above, [click](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.1/).